# 3d Graphics in PSL1GHT

Tags: c, playstation3

Is there any way of having 3d graphics in PSL1GHT? If so, please explain how to set up PSL1GHT to work with 3d graphics. I don't know much about programming in general, so please be specific.

Thanks in advance, cheeseisedible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: 
PSL1GHT supports libgmc and especially openGL via PSGL. Currently there is no easy howto on this topic on the net. But you can just try to google for psl1ght +opengl to see some demos about the base possibilities. 
I would suggest you start the classic way with "hello world" before running into the 3D-topics

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been waiting for 2 months to get an answer to this question. However, I have no way of testing anything I program for the ps3, because I updated it. Oh well...